# Darken a shadow on a shadow catcher without changing the light on the object casting it? (Blender Cycles 2.81)

Tags: cycles-render-engine, light, shadows, shadowcatcher

I am making a very short video in which a miniature dalek model (https://www.blendswap.com/blend/6326) goes around my table, and I made a shadow catcher plane, and I wanted to make the shadow brighter without making the object brighter. Strangely enough, in the render viewport, the image looks just as I want it.

[image]

(This is the image when in the render viewport)

[image]

(however this is the image when properly rendered)

As far as I can tell, this scene has two light sources, a HDRI environment texture and a "window" that I modeled approximately to the shape of our window, that I just added an emission texture, to simulate the light of the real window.

I would be hugely grateful if anyone can help with this.

Thanks.

And sorry about the rubbish formating. I am new and not very familiar with this yet.

Comment: One way is using compositing: isolate your shadow and use brightness/contrast or Color Correction before composing it with your robot.

Comment: I was thinking something possibly like that, but I was thinking if it looks right in the render view in the viewport, then why doesn't it in the actual render.

Comment: it might be that you're just lucky with the viewport result as it has a lot of simplification vs the final render which is supposed to be more physically accurate. The problem is that Shadow Catcher in itself is not physically accurate, adding some unpredictability to the process.

Comment: Yes, probably. :( Thanks though.